# Werewolves and sense of smell, what is reasonable for them to accomplish with it?

Tags: biology, biochemistry, werewolf

I was thinking of a story with a Werewolf as a detective, using mostly conversational skills and his sense of smell to solve crimes similar to many of the UK types of detective stories (Morse, Lewis, Frost, Dielzy and Pasco etc), in contrast to most American detective stories I watch where practically no episode goes by without a shootout or guns being drawn by the detectives in question (these have their own merits ofcourse).

I've read a lot of stories where enhanced sense of smell does any number of things, the most extreme of which are things like smelling what kind of diet someone has lived on for their entire lives or what kind of house they lived in half a year ago. The sense of smell is also used as shortcut where a character simply smells someone lying. But could you really sift through the layers of emotions and tell apart a lie from a half-truth to save face or the difference between guilt of killing a person or guilt because the last words you said were insulting or a bit too close to what happened (like "drop dead")?

Assuming the sense of smell of this particular werewolf is akin to that of a dog or wolf (excluding extreme dogbreeds that have diminished sense of smell) what could you expect from a sense of smell this powerful?<-- That there is the question. I would like to know it in these categories:

1. Where someone or something has been in the last X time.
2. What someone has eaten in the last X time.
3. How accurate you can smell social cue's.

These are 3 separate questions with so much overlap I don't see a reason to separate them at this point.

Comment: I think you should watch Ukrainian crime series The Sniffer. It's on netflix.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Is The Sniffer accurate in terms of sense of smell or is it simply the same take as the story I want to write but with randomly guessed attributes for the sense of smell?

Comment: It's been some time when I've watched but it was closer to European detective story. In a way that Smell replaced obsevation but drawed to conculsion based on knowledge and psychology.

Comment: This seems a bit wild to assume the sense of smell could detect any of that. Honestly I would draw the line at the last time someone took a shower or used the toilet. It is kind of a known thing that using water and mud is a good way to throw off animal tracking. IIt makes to kno someone has been in a certain place, if you are at that place and smell the person, but not for how long. You might be able to get dietary stuff from bodily waste, but even that can only stretch so far. Smelling social cues makes absolutely no sense to me, do you mean like pheromones reflecting mood or intent maybe?

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle the Mythbusters tested a ton of them. Walking through water for example did not mislead the dog or even phase him. Most methods, including washing yourself and wearing a no-scent suit didnt work either. The problem is: finding someone might be easy, but the rest?

Comment: @Demigan yes the dog can still find the person by that individual person's scent that they continuously give off, but why would they be able to smell where that person has been after they have washed the scent of the other place off?

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle well that is the question. How many particles would remain on you after washing and how many would be needed to be detected by a dog's sense of smell. Looking at how people are washed after nuclear dust exposure some would still remain during "normal" washing, just like bacteria arent gone from your skin after washing (which is good).

Answer (score 2):

Given that dogs can smell when someone is pregnant, ovulating, about to have a seizure, possibly cancer, certainly many illnesses, drugs through plastic bags even when they've been washed, and famously tracking a person after a day or so. Coupled with the fact that a wolfs sense of smell is 2-3 times better (can smell blood from 50 miles away better). In wolf form I don't think it's unreasonable to be able to smell what sort of diet someone has had long term. In human form I'd consider it to be inferior to a dogs sense of smell, but much better than a humans.

I would say that it's something that needs to be trained or grown up with, as it's all well and good having the information, but unless you know how to translate it or doesn't matter.

Oh and don't forget stress hormones smell, and hearing also plays a large part. So as a human lie detector, they could tell when someone's stress levels spike during questioning, but not why.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- If they claim they never saw the victim, but the victim's scent is on them, or some other scent associated with the victim's location.
- The opposite: a person's scent is on the victim.
- The scent of blood on a suspect or their clothes, or perhaps at the scene where it's suspect the crime took place but has since been cleaned. This one is a good one, because (assuming the detective is keeping the fact they're a werewolf secret), they can make up some bullshit story about seeing some kind of trace of blood and seeing how the suspect reacts.
- Sniffing out where something related to the crime is hidden. This again is pretty good because you can probably make up some bullshit story about noticing some tiny detail that other people would accept.

There are others, but as Demigan noted, there's a difference between knowing someone committed a crime and proving someone committed a crime. At that point, your detective is basically going to have to go the Columbo route: once they know who the killer is, they've got to find a way of manipulating them into outing themselves or revealing evidence that other people could pick up.

Answer (score 1):

There are some limits to what smell can do in an intelligent life form. Most animals with a good sense of smell have a large percentage of their brains devoted to olfactory processing. They can do amazing things, but it comes at a cost. Given the supernatural nature of werewolves, it would be reasonable that a 'human' form of a werewolf might have little better sense than a man. Transformed, the character might become much less intelligent as his brain is overtaken with olfactory processors. I like limitations on characters. Perhaps they must transform to use their smell, but can 'remember' when in human form. Alternatively, the character may be unable to pump gas or tolerate the smell of gunpowder. For useful guidance, look up bloodhounds and the things people have trained them to detect.

Comment: Limitations on characters can be created BECAUSE they have superpowers. Spiderman is a prime example of someone juggling social life, growing up and heroism. The werewolf might need to hide what (s)he is, or fight bias from people who think (s)he's dangerous, or during his work (s)he has to find out if the murderer is supernatural and if so hide this from non-supernatural people and not get this murderer convicted, but subsequently do get enough evidence to get the murderer caught and convicted by a (hidden) supernatural court. The limitation is set by the story's setting.